# find wheather a particular index element is present in map or not ??

Tags: string, dictionary, null, key, compare

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <string>
        #include <map>
        using namespace std;

        map <int ,string> m;
        map <int ,string> ::iterator it;


        if(m[key]=='\0')

         {key=key +1;
            }
```

i need to find weather int **key** has a allocated value in map **m** or not .how do i do it???
Actually  i need to allocate a string to the key if the key if the key is already filled i will choose another one.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to check if the key is in the map is:

```
if (m.find(key) == M.end())
    //key is not in map
```